# Ruby: How to estimate per hour ec2 costs?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I would like to be able to estimate the per hour cost of specific ec2 instances in my aws accounts using [Aws::Pricing::Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/Pricing/Client.html#get_products-instance_method) or another module inside of the ruby aws-sdk gem.

However, I do find the documentation a bit confusing and could use some help in finding a good example on how to use this module. For example, how would I be able to use this to find the cost of an ec2 instance with a size of `m3.medium`, in `us-east-1`, with a `50 gb` `gp2` volume?

Better yet is there is a method I could use to give some aws-sdk module the instance id or name and receive an estimate of the per hour costs on that instance?

Comment: Side-note: The cost of EC2 is separate to the cost for EBS volumes.

Comment: did you look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/Budgets.html and  https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-budgets/ ?

Comment: you might be looking for https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CostExplorer/Client.html#instance_method_details

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes the cost of EC2 and EBS are separate, but it seemed that some aws-sdk cost estimation modules might be able to do both calculations at once. However it seems that I will likely require two separate modules to calculate the full cost .

Comment: @lacostenycoder I love the `Aws::CostExplorer` sugesstion! Unfourtunately it only seems to be available for `us-east-1` :( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#billing_region

Comment: @AlexCohen I think that may be the endpoint where the services is hosted, but since `:region` is required option I think you might be mistaken. Did you give it a try?
see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CostExplorer/Client.html#constructor_details and search for `:region`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that there is no direct `aws-sdk` module that can be used to access ec2 and ebs costs across all regions.  However, it seems that the [AWS pricing API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-price-list-api/) will be the closest solution providing costs for both resources across all aws regions.

More details on this api can be found in this post: [get ec2 pricing programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334035/get-ec2-pricing-programmatically)

The api produces jsonp files. To make this easily accessible in ruby I would then recommend taking a look at this post that uses examples direcly from the pricing API: [Ruby : How to parse a jsonp and save json data to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641162/ruby-how-to-parse-a-jsonp-and-save-json-data-to-database)

Fair warning, you will need to parse this heavily to be able to access any information. For example, this solution will provide a hash containing the pricing data for a `t2.medium` instance in `us-west-2`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'net/http'
require 'json'

ec2_linux_price = JSON.parse(
  Net::HTTP.get(
    URI.parse('http://a0.awsstatic.com/pricing/1/ec2/linux-od.min.js')
  ).split('callback(')[1].sub(');', '').gsub(/(\w+):/, '"\1":')
)

region_prices = ec2_linux_price["config"]["regions"].select{|region| 
  region["region"]=="us-west-2"
}[0]["instanceTypes"].map{|types| 
  types["sizes"]
}

cost_hash={}
region_prices.each do |size_range| 
  cost = size_range.select{|size| 
    size["size"]==instance[:instance_type]
  }[0]
  unless cost.nil?
    cost_hash["t2.medium"] = cost["valueColumns"][0]["prices"]["USD"]
  end
end

p cost_hash
```